# Use JSON value as HTML tag with vue

Tags: html, json, parsing, vue.js

I have a JSON file outputting the following styles:

```
{
"h1" : {
    "font-family" : "Lato",
    "font-size" : "24px",
    "line-height" : "28px",
    "font-weight" : 600,
    "colorId" : 3,
    "margin-bottom" : "10px",
    "margin-top" : "20px"
},
"h2" : {
    "font-family" : "Lato",
    "font-size" : "20px",
    "line-height" : "24px",
    "font-weight" : 600,
    "colorId" : 3,
    "margin-bottom" : "10px",
    "margin-top" : "20px"
}
```

}

I want to use the first key "h1, h2, ..." as an HTML tag to display it. Is this possible with Vue?

It should be something like this:

```
<div v-for="(props, tag) in headers">
    <{{ tag }}>x</ {{ tag }}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div v-for="(props, tag) in headers" v-html="`<${tag}>x</${tag}>`"></div>
```

Comment: That is nice! Thanks. How about adding styles? <div v-for="(props, tag) in headers" v-html="`<${tag} v-bind:style='${props}'>This is a ${ tag }-header</${tag}>`"></div>

Comment: This way it's not possible to bind any properties to it. You pass a static html string to 'v-html'. But you can add a function that builds the html.

    <div v-for="(props, tag) in headers" v-html="buildHtml(props, tag)"></div>

    buildHtml(props, tag) {
        return `<${tag}` +
           Object.keys(props).reduce((total, key) => { return total + ` ${key}:${props[key]});
        +`>`
        + `x`
        +`<${tag}>`
    }